How to deserialize a JSON input as a generic datastructure in Rust?
Most examples showing deserialization of JSON with Rust and serde_json show deserialization into a known structure format, using a defined struct.
Is it possible to deserialize a JSON document with an unknown structure into a generic Rust datatype which can handle this structural variance?
For example, I tried something like this
let filename = "example.json";
let maybe_ifile = std::fs::File::open(filename);

match maybe_ifile {
    Ok(ifile) => {
        let maybe_json_data = serde_json::from_reader::<_, BTreeMap<String, String>>(ifile);

        match maybe_json_data {
            Ok(json_data) => {
                println!("{json_data:?}");
            }

            Err(error) => {
                panic!("{error}")
            }
        }
    }

    Err(error) => {
        panic!("{error}");
    }
}

This works if the JSON document is structured as pairs of key-value strings, but it does not work for more general structures, so clearly using BTreeMap<String, String> is not the right approach here.
What I am trying to achieve is flexibility using runtime / somewhat dynamic types.
This is possible in other languages, so I would assume there is a fairly trivial solution in Rust, I am just not aware of what this is.

The solution was to use the serde_json::Value datatype. This provides a generic way to work with JSON data.
The single line changed:
let maybe_json_data = serde_json::from_reader::<_, serde_json::Value>(ifile);

Example deserialize generic JSON Document
Here's an example of deserializing a JSON string into a serde_json::Value:
use serde_json::Value;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // Example JSON string
    let json_str = r#"
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 30,
        "is_member": true,
        "favorites": {
            "colors": ["red", "green", "blue"],
            "numbers": [1, 2, 3]
        }
    }
    "#;

    // Parse the JSON string into a serde_json::Value
    let json_value: Value = serde_json::from_str(json_str)?;

    // Accessing elements in the JSON
    if let Some(name) = json_value.get("name").and_then(|v| v.as_str()) {
        println!("Name: {}", name);
    }

    if let Some(age) = json_value.get("age").and_then(|v| v.as_i64()) {
        println!("Age: {}", age);
    }

    if let Some(is_member) = json_value.get("is_member").and_then(|v| v.as_bool()) {
        println!("Is Member: {}", is_member);
    }

    // Nested JSON objects
    if let Some(favorites) = json_value.get("favorites") {
        if let Some(colors) = favorites.get("colors").and_then(|v| v.as_array()) {
            println!("Favorite Colors: {:?}", colors);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

Explanation
Parsing JSON: The serde_json::from_str function parses the JSON string into a serde_json::Value.
Accessing Data: Use the get method to access fields in the JSON. You can further use type-specific methods like as_str, as_i64, and as_bool to convert the JSON values to Rust types.
Handling Nested and Complex JSON
The serde_json::Value enum can represent JSON data of any structure:

Value::Object for JSON objects
Value::Array for arrays
Value::String for strings
Value::Number for numbers
Value::Bool for booleans
Value::Null for nulls

This makes it suitable for generic JSON deserialization when the structure is not fixed.
